# maxconn limit per backend in haproxy

Tags: networking, connection, load-balancing, haproxy

Our haproxy loadbalancer opens thousands of connections to its backends
even though its settings say to open no more than 10 connections per server instance (see below). When I uncomment "option http-server-close"  the number of backend connection drops however I would like to have keep-alive backend connections.

Why maxconn is not respected with `http-keep-alive`? I verified with `ss` that the opened backend connections are in `ESTABLISHED` state.

```
defaults
     log global
     mode    http
     option http-keep-alive
     timeout http-keep-alive 60000
     timeout connect 6000
     timeout client  60000
     timeout server  20000


 frontend http_proxy
     bind    *:80
     default_backend backends

 backend backends
     option prefer-last-server

     # option http-server-close
     timeout http-keep-alive 1000
     server s1 10.0.0.21:8080 maxconn 10
     server s2 10.0.0.7:8080  maxconn 10
     server s3 10.0.0.22:8080 maxconn 10
     server s4 10.0.0.16:8080 maxconn 10
```

Comment: please can you pastebin the output of haproxy -vv thanks. Maybe you have hit a know bug http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In keep-alive mode **idle connections** are not accounted. As explained in this HAProxy [mailthread](https://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg27034.html)

> The thing is, you don't want
>   to leave requests waiting in a server's queue while the server has a ton
>   of idle connections.

This even makes more sense, knowing that browsers initiate preconnect to improve page performance. So in keep-alive mode only outstanding/active connections are taken into account.

You can still enforce maxconn limits regardless of the connection state using **tcp mode**, especially that I don't see a particular reason to using mode http in your current configuration (apart from having reacher logs).
Or you can use [http-reuse](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-http-reuse) with http mode to achieve a lowest number of concurrent connections.